# Python trouble with nose

Tags: python, ubuntu, nose

I am having some trouble with LPTHW on Exercise 46 in which we create a skeleton directory for a future project and install pip among other things. I have having a problem with nosetests. Whenever I run it I get a problem. I have everything set up as he wants me to.
Here is the problem (I am running Ubuntu 12.04)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/nosetests", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('nose==1.3.0', 'console_scripts', 'nosetests')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 337, in  load_entry_point
  return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2279, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1989, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from nose.core import collector, main, run, run_exit, runmodule
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/core.py", line 11, in <module>
    from nose.config import Config, all_config_files
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/config.py", line 9, in <module>
    from nose.plugins.manager import NoPlugins
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/plugins/__init__.py", line 184, in     <module>
    from nose.plugins.base import Plugin
EOFError: EOF read where object expected
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. When I installed Nose the first time, I didn't 'sudo' it and it never installed. And I cicked out of terminal before I saw it. At least. that's what I thought happened. I deleted nose and reinstalled it and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly get the same error. I fix this by removing `--with-id` from the argument.
I used it previously.
It works now.